# how could i change the string data format ..?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The data format, which I get from back-end is

```
{
  "2020-08-22": 1425,
  "2020-08-23": 1475,
  "2020-08-24": 1475,
  "flightnumber": "EK-853",
  "source": "emirates",
  "stops": "stops-0"
}
```

Is that possible to change the key data as following

```
{
  "Aug 22": 1425,
  "Aug 23": 1475,
  "Aug 24": 1475,
  "flightnumber": "EK-853",
  "source": "emirates",
  "stops": "stops-0"
}
```

Please tell me some solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below snippet could help you. It has several things to notice:

- iterate through object's keys
- object's dynamic key
- detect invalid date

```js
const data = {
  "2020-08-22": 1425,
  "2020-08-23": 1475,
  "2020-08-24": 1475,
  flightnumber: "EK-853",
  source: "emirates",
  stops: "stops-0",
}

const monthNames = [
  "Jan",
  "Feb",
  "Mar",
  "Apr",
  "May",
  "Jun",
  "Jul",
  "Aug",
  "Sep",
  "Oct",
  "Nov",
  "Dec",
]

const res = {}

Object.keys(data).forEach((k) => {
  const date = new Date(k)

  if (!isNaN(date.getTime())) {
    res[`${monthNames[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getDate()}`] = data[k]
  } else {
    res[k] = data[k]
  }
})

console.log(res)
```